# Can't load Android Emulator with Google API's

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-api

There is the following problem - I want to execute an Android emulator with API v14, and I've done it without any problem. But now I need to do it with Google API's, and I'm trying to do it using Android Google API's v14, but the emulator doesn't work! It has been loading and showing "Android" title on the screen 20 minutes yet. How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you show us the arguments your providing when you create the emulator? The google images often stored elsewhere. Are you on windows or otherwise?

Comment: So you're using the avd manager GUI? What's your target and CPU/ABI?

Answer (score 0):

change size of Ram up to 1024 MB, it's work for me